# Google Test WillOnce(Return( )) manipulates the expected return-value

Tags: c++, unit-testing, return-value, googletest, googlemock

I am currently trying to test the capabilities of google test in c++. (To be more specific: google mock)

Now I ran into a problem. It should be super easy, it worked before, but somehow it got messed up and the framework isn't working as expected. Enough talk, here is my problem.

I try to do the simple thing to see if the function "DoSomeMathTurtle" gets invoked once and returns the expected value. But ".WillOnce(Return(x))" manipulates the expected value that it is always true.

```
class Turtle {
    ...
    virtual int DoSomeMathTurtle(int , int); //Adds two ints together and returns them
    ...
};
```

My mocking class:

```
    class MockTurtle : public Turtle{
    public:
        MockTurtle(){
            ON_CALL(*this, DoSomeMathTurtle(_, _))
                .WillByDefault(Invoke(&real_, Turtle::DoSomeMathTurtle)); 
            //I did this so the function gets redirected to a real
            // object so those two numbers actually get added together 
            //(without that it returns always 0)

        }
        MOCK_METHOD2(DoSomeMathTurtle, int(int, int));
    private:
        Turtle real_;
    };
```

Basic Testing Class:

```
class TestTurtle : public ::testing::Test{
protected:
    //De- & Constructor
    TestTurtle(){}
    virtual ~TestTurtle(){} //Has to be virtual or all tests will fail

    //Code executed before and after every test
    virtual void SetUp(){}
    virtual void TearDown(){}

    //Test Fixtures which can be used in each test
    MockTurtle m_turtle;
 };
```

My Testcase:

```
    TEST_F(TestTurtle, MathTest){
            int x = 2; // Expected value
            int rvalue; // Returned value of the function

            EXPECT_CALL(m_turtle, DoSomeMathTurtle(_, _))
                .Times(1)
                .WillOnce(Return(x));

                rvalue = m_turtle.DoSomeMathTurtle(3,3); // rvalue should be 6 but it is 2
                cout << "[          ] Expected value: " << x << " Returned value " << rvalue << endl;
                //This prints: [          ] Expected value 2 Returned value 2
                //Then the test passes !?
            }
        }
```

When I comment the `"WillOnce(Return(x))"` out, rvalue becomes 6 (the value it should become). When `"WillOnce(Return(x))"` &

```
ON_CALL(*this, DoSomeMathTurtle(_, _))
                .WillByDefault(Invoke(&real_, Turtle::DoSomeMathTurtle));
```

(in the constructor of my mock-class) is commented out, rvalue becomes 0 (that should also happen).

So as soon as `"WillOnce(Return(x))"` is in the game, rvalue is always `"x"`.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Have a nice, bug-free day!

Comment: This is desired behaviour for mock. You can imagine that you have some class that fetch data form disk. You normally avoid using disk in unit test. So you mock you class and tell it what you expect it to return to you. This is completely fine and there is no bug in here.

Comment: So if a understand that right: To save disk space I tell gmock "what the function will return" instead of "setting up a comparissen that has to match" to make the test pass?

Comment: But where is the implementation of `DoSomeMathTurtle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock is all about expectations. When you write in your test:

```
EXPECT_CALL(m_turtle, DoSomeMathTurtle(_, _))
  .Times(1)
  .WillOnce(Return(x));
```

You expect that `m_turtle` will call one time `DoSomeMathTurtle` that will take any arguments and that will one time `return x`.

Because `x` is equal to 2, then when next time when you use `m_turtle.DoSomeMathTurtle(any_argument, any_argument);` 
it will return 2.

If you want check arguments,you should look for matchers in googlemock, f.e when you make

```
EXPECT_CALL(m_turtle, DoSomeMathTurtle(Eq(3), Lt(3)))
```

you will expect that `DoSomeMathTurtle` will take two arguments when first is equal to 3 and second is smaller than 3.

If you want get good result in your test you can just write:

```
EXPECT_CALL(m_turtle, DoSomeMathTurtle(Eq(3), Eq(3)))
  .Times(1)
  .WillOnce(Return(6));
  rvalue = m_turtle.DoSomeMathTurtle(3,3); // rvalue is equal to 6
```